# Time stamp not converted in date properly in java

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, timestamp

I'm trying to convert a time stamp into date using this code:

```
String str = "14799744000000800";//last four digit is time zone
 DateFormat timeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 timeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

 Date time = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(str));
 System.out.println(timeZoneFormat.format(time));
```

But it prints '21-03-**470955** 00:00:00'  instead of 21-03-2016 00:00:00.

As you can see year part is not converted properly.how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that your milliseconds value is correct? As far as I can see this conversion is ok. 21-03-2016 is 1458518400000 milliseconds when your value 14799744000000800 is much bigger

Comment: last four digit is time zone like this 1479974400000-0800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current milliseconds value is `1481007881541`, so `14799744000000800` does seem to be really in the future.

**Edit**
As per your later comments, you could just remove last four digit from string.

Comment: last four digit is time zone like this 1479974400000-0800

Comment: The idea of you code is that the date is accepting a Long value that is the number of seconds since the epoch.  A Date is always GMT, it is only the display of it that may be in different TZ